# Cannot build RabbitMQ plugin because of missing dependencies

Tags: makefile, erlang, rabbitmq, hex-pm

I would like to start working on my own RabbitMQ plugin, but I cannot build https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella from source code on clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed everything neccessary as described in https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html. 
Every time I hit `make co` I receive following error:

`make[2]: Entering directory '/opt/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/deps/rabbit_common'
 DEP    lager
tar: /opt/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/.erlang.mk/hex/lager.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
erlang.mk:4710: recipe for target '/opt/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/deps/lager' failed
make[2]: *** [/opt/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/deps/lager] Error 2`

It happens randomly for every dependency which is expected to be in **/.erlang.mk/hex/** directory (lager, ranch, jsx), but this directory is empty (no tar file downloaded).
The same issue persist when I try to build some existing plugin like https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-http on its own.

I am sure I was able to compile the code successfully two days ago and tar files were downloaded to **/.erlang.mk/hex/** when running **make**. I am new to Erlang and all the development tools related to it, so maybe I am missing something.

It's possible that **hex.pm** is not working? I tried everything - restarting the machine, make distclean, I did even create a new VM with Ubuntu on other network but the issue persists.

Comment: For your question to be on-topic, you'd need an MCVE. However, maybe this is just the wrong place to ask. Instead, check out the project history (maybe something changed since you last built it?) and reread the installation instructions. If nothing helps, maybe a support request filed at their project page would help them to improve the build instructions. Lastly, it could also be your system. Have you tried building any other things?

Comment: You are right, this wasn't the best place to ask - I was just desperate. However it started working today, there were probably issues with one of the parties providing dependency modules.

Comment: Okay, so you have a problem that is not fully described with a solution that involves someone else changing something else somewhere. Please delete your question, there's IMHO no need for it here.

Answer (score 0):

It started working today, it was probably an issue with some server providing third party-dependencies (like hex)